# How to get the id's of children and grandchildren of a category edit laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I would like to get all the products that fall under a certain category. 
I have a table of categories that can have up to 3 levels.

```
->grandparent category
------>Parent category
-------------> Child category
```

I have a table of products that can fall under any one of these categories (`category_id` field). If I select a grandparent category I would like to be able to fetch all products such that:

- The product `category_id` matches the grandparent category
- The product `category_id` field matches a parent category that is a child of the grandparent category.
- The product `category_id` field matches
  a child category that is a child of a parent category that is a child
  of the grandparent category.

I have the following code:

```
$category = Category::select('id')
    ->where('parent_id', $category->id)
    ->orWhere('id', $category->id)
    ->get();
```

The results is a list of Id's which I then use to query the product table. The problem with this code is that it only gets me one level down (i.e the grandparent and parents that fall under it).

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can try a "recursion" function:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Grandparents extends Model {

  protected $table = 'your table';

  protected $with = [ 'children' ];

  protected $visible = [ 'id', 'children' ];

  public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany( Grandparents::class, 'parent_id', 'id' )->with( 'children' );
  }
}
```

And then check if the results are ok:

```
print_r( \App\Models\Grandparents::where( 'id', '=', 1000 )->get()->toArray() );
```

Regards,
Lukas